# finding duplicates in MySQL with a null field when some SHOULD have a null field

Tags: mysql

Need some help from a MySQL expert here. I have a terrible database to work with and I'm trying to fix the structure a bit but this one has me baffled. The table initially had an id, name and 4 sell columns. I converted that to an id, name and single sell column as basically a pivot table. That was fine, next issue was to get rid of duplicates since not every entry had 4 sell entries.

So after the first operation I ended up with something like this:

```
id     name     sellid
1      bob      111
1      bob      
1      bob      
2      mary     112
2      mary     113
2      mary     114
2      mary     115
3      fred
3      fred
3      fred
3      fred
```

So by doing group by I managed to get it to the point where it looks like this:

```
id     name     sellid
1      bob      111
1      bob      
2      mary     112
2      mary     113
2      mary     114
2      mary     115
3      fred
```

Now here is where I hit a wall. Fred is fine, he is supposed to have an entry but no sellid, Mary is also fine she has all 4 sellids full. Bob is the issue. How do I remove the empty sellid for him without affecting Fred?

I'd say what I tried but I am just at a complete loss here so I really haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: And the reason for the random downvote on a week old question would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for an [outer join](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) between your names and other data:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT id, name FROM my_table) t1 NATURAL LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE sellid IS NOT NULL) t2
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0496/1/0).

But really, you should [normalise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your schema further so that you have a table of `(personid, name)` and a table of `(personid, sellid)` pairs (from which you essentially perform the above outer join as & when required to obtain the necessary records including `NULL`s).

Comment: Perfect, didn't work at first because apparently it wasn't null I had to do <>'' rather than null. I'm in the process of better normalisation but the data needs to be updated automatically from an external source every so often and that means changing those routines to fit the new data structure. So yeah you're right but slowly but surely. Thanks very much!